# GAE After deploy error: 404 page not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an issue in configuring Remote_API to copy entities between 2 applications. I deployed new version. It says deployed sucessfully and after deployment it shows this message [image]

wen i try to run this in web browser it says follwing error "***This request did not contain a necessary header***"

Where am i commiting mistake. I need to enable Remote api in my application.

Help me in solving this issue.

Comment: "WordPad: Failed to open document" ???  Are you sure this is the screen shot you intended to post?

Comment: yes. I get this after i deploy the new version.

Comment: Your title is confusing with respect to the rest of your question.  I suggest that you rewrite the title and explain in the rest of your question how you're configuring [Remote API for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi), and when you're seeing each of the three error messages listed in your post.